# How do you update a label every time text is typed into a textbox, using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, label

I'm trying to create an app where a part of it involves a label that dynamically changes and displays the number of characters typed within the textbox every time it gets updated. I couldn't find any information regarding this and unsure whether this is even possible.

Comment: Is the textbox a `tkinter.Entry` or `tkinter.Text`?

Comment: its a tkinter.Text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a simpler solution that requires a bit more work by the caller, look at this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def callback(event):
    # After 1 ms call `_callback`
    # That is to make sure that tkinter has handled the keyboard press
    root.after(1, _callback)

def _callback():
    # The `-1` is there because when you have `text_widget.get(..., "end")`
    # It adds a "\n" character at then end
    number_of_chars = len(text_widget.get("1.0", "end")) - 1
    print(number_of_chars)

root = tk.Tk()
text_widget = tk.Text(root)
text_widget.pack()

text_widget.bind("<Key>", callback)

root.mainloop()
```

This basically binds all keyboard presses to the `callback` function. I can't think of any way to change the text in a text widget without pressing a keyboard button.

Please note that it will only run when a key is pressed so it wouldn't work if you called `text_widget.insert` or `text_widget.delete` (@acw1668 found that problem). It is the caller's responsibility to call `_callback` just after they call `.insert`/`.delete`.

Comment: `"<KeyRelease>"` would work better in this case.

Comment: The documented first character in a text widget is `"1.0"`, not `"0.0"`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Same thing. It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @JacksonPro Why? `<Key>` works for when you hold the key.

Comment: @TheLizzard KeyRelease is triggered when the key is released hence you wouldn't need to use `root.after`

Comment: Your solution does not cater changes via `.insert()`.

Comment: @JacksonPro That event is triggered just before the key release not after so I still need the `root.after`.

Comment: @acw1668 I will edit my answer with a comment saying that the caller should call `_callback` whenever they call `.insert`/`.delete`/...

Comment: @TheLizzard did you bind "KeyRelease" event to `_callback()`.?

Comment: Correct that `"0.0"` works, but when you are trying to teach someone who doesn't know much about tkinter it's good to use best programming practices. They might otherwise be left with the impression that `"0.0"` and `"1.0"` represent different characters, leading to confusion later.

Comment: @BryanOakley I don't want to have that argument again (we already had it a few weeks ago). I will edit my answer.

Comment: @JacksonPro My bad :D. But it doesn't update until the user releases the key.

Comment: thanks for the help guys! I can work with this.

Answer (score 4):

The most foolproof way to get notified when the text widget changes is to intercept the low-level insert, delete, and replace commands. When they occur, an event can be generated, which you can then bind to.

This involves a tiny bit of tcl voodoo, but it works, and works whether you type into the widget, paste using the mouse, or directly call the insert or delete methods.

Here is a complete example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """A text widget that supports a <<TextChanged>> event"""
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.tk.eval('''
            proc widget_proxy {widget widget_command args} {

                # call the real tk widget command with the real args
                set result [uplevel [linsert $args 0 $widget_command]]

                # if the contents changed, generate an event we can bind to
                if {([lindex $args 0] in {insert replace delete})} {
                    event generate $widget <<TextModified>> -when tail
                }
                # return the result from the real widget command
                return $result
            }

        ''')

        # this replaces the underlying widget with the proxy
        self.tk.eval('''
            rename {widget} _{widget}
            interp alias {{}} ::{widget} {{}} widget_proxy {widget} _{widget}
        '''.format(widget=str(self)))

def update_char_count(event):
    count = event.widget.count("1.0", "end-1c")
    # count is a tuple; the character count is the first element
    count = 0 if not count else count[0]
    label.configure(text=f"Characters: {count}")

root = tk.Tk()
text = CustomText(root)
label = tk.Label(root, anchor="w")
label.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text.bind("<<TextModified>>", update_char_count)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for! thanks mate.

Comment: I have seen this somewhere already but the functions were written in python. I can't remember where :D.

Comment: Yes, the python version I wrote is buggy. I've never take the time to figure out the root cause. The tcl version works fine though.

Comment: Well to understand this, I will have to lean the tcl syntax. Guess what I will be doing for the next few days :D. Why do you rename the widget? Also is there a way to return `"break"` from the event? In my solution there isn't.

Comment: @TheLizzard: the widget is renamed so that the original widget command still exists after it is replaced with the proxy. The proxy then calls the original command to do what was requested before firing the event.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I don't understand your question about returning `"break"`. Yes, the bound function can return `"break"` but it won't really cause anything to happen since there are no other bindings to the `<<TextChanged>>` event.

Comment: @BryanOakley So you are creating a virtual widget named `<widget>` and renaming the real one to `_<widget>`. If you call a method/function on `<widget>`, it goes to `_<widget>` which can trigger the `<<TextModified>>` event. What happens if an error occurs in `_<widget>`? Could you still use `try`/`except` to catch the error? I remember that I had that problem with the last implementation.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I don't know what you mean by "virtual widget". There's no such thing in tk. Every widget has a command which can be used to manipulate the widget. This solution replaces that command with a custom command. This custom command calls the original command and then generates an event. And yes, you can use try/except.

Comment: @BryanOakley have you looked at `idlelib.redirector.WidgetRedirector`? I think it is the same thing as you did but packaged in a library that you can just call.

Comment: @TheLizzard: yes, I've looked at WidgetRedirector.

Answer (score 2):

An even simpler answer is always to use what someone has already created :D

```py
# `idlelib` is part of the standard library
from idlelib.redirector import WidgetRedirector
import tkinter as tk

def my_insert(*args):
    original_insert(*args)
    update_label()

def my_delete(*args):
    original_delete(*args)
    update_label()

def my_replace(*args):
    original_replace(*args)
    update_label()

def update_label():
    number_of_chars = len(text.get("1.0", "end")) - 1
    print(number_of_chars)

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

redir = WidgetRedirector(text)
original_insert = redir.register("insert", my_insert)
original_delete = redir.register("delete", my_delete)
original_replace = redir.register("replace", my_replace)

root.mainloop()
```

This solution works even if you use `text.insert(...)`

For more info on how it works just use `help(WidgetRedirector)`.

Comment: Why are you using `after`? Why not just call `update_label` after calling the original function rather than before?

Comment: @BryanOakley Well... I think my brain died. I will edit my answer

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the suggestion.